# "Extract range is not defined": advanced filter

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run this simple code in VBA but it keeps giving me "extract range is not defined" error:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Dim rng As Range
    Dim RowLast As Long
    Dim perporig As Workbook
    count = 0
    Set perporig = Workbooks.Open("\\Etnfps02\vol1\DATA\Inventory\Daily tracking\perpetual.xlsx", , ReadOnly)
    With perporig.Sheets("perpetual")
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        RowLast = .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        'Set rng = .Range("C4:C" & RowLast)
        Range("A3:J" & RowLast).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=Range("N1:N6"), Unique:=False 'have also tried Range("A3:J3"), doesn't work.

    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("myperpetual").Range("A5", "J5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

I am trying to copy from a file with data starting from A4:J4 to some A16000:J16000. I have to filter the values in column C to a range I have specified in the worksheet in range N1:N6.
FYI: Table header A4 is empty, and B4:J4 have relevant headers in them.
Also please let me know if my copy-paste method is wrong, or for some reason wouldn't work as expected.

EDIT: I also tried adding a header in column A , i.e. cell A3. Still doesn't work.
My range N1:N6 is a list of numbers, but I am sure the mistake lies there. It doesn't specify which column to apply filter on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you are inside the `With perporig.Sheets("perpetual") ... End With` block, preface all [Range objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) and [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx) references with a period (aka `.` or *full stop*).

```
With perporig.Sheets("perpetual")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    RowLast = .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    'Set rng = .Range("C4:C" & RowLast)
    .Range("A3:J" & RowLast).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=.Range("N1:N6"), Unique:=False
End With
```

Note `.Range("C4:C"...` and `.Range("N1:N6")` prefaced with a period. This indicates that the parent worksheet of the range(s) are defined by the worksheet named in the [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx). Without it, Excel is making a guess as to which worksheet the range belongs to; typically this would be the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Comment: My criteria range would be in the other sheet, not preporig. It doesn't need a "." right? Can I use a thisworkbook.sheets().range()?

Comment: I did what you mentioned and what I said above, now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear you got sorted and thanks for taking the time to share the combined solution.